# PHP Array_Fill_Keys & Array_Sum on Sequential and Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have two arrays as follows:

```
$arr1 = array("apple","banana","lemon");
$arr2 = array("apple"=>4,"banana"=>1,"lemon"=>1);
```

And I use array_fill_keys to fill the above arrays:

```
$arr3 = array_fill_keys($arr1,1);
$arr4 = array_fill_keys($arr2,1);
```

When I do an array_sum for those 4 arrays above like this:

```
echo "Sum of Array1 is " . array_sum($arr1) . "\n";
echo "Sum of Array2 is " . array_sum($arr2) . "\n";
echo "Sum of Array3 is " . array_sum($arr3) . "\n";
echo "Sum of Array4 is " . array_sum($arr4) . "\n";
```

The result will be:

```
Sum of Array1 is 0
Sum of Array2 is 6
Sum of Array3 is 3
Sum of Array4 is 2
```

Why does Array4 return 2 instead of 3?

Answer (score 1):

Lets simplify this here are your arrays

```
$arr1 = array("apple","banana","lemon");
$arr2 = array("apple"=>4,"banana"=>1,"lemon"=>1);

//$arr3 = array_fill_keys($arr1,1);
$arr3 = array("apple"=>1,"banana"=>1,"lemon"=>1);
//$arr4 = array_fill_keys($arr2,1);
$arr4 = array(1=>1, 4=>1);
```

As you can see array #4 ( $arr4 ) has these keys added using array_fill_keys

```
array( 4, 1, 1 );
```

These are the values of $arr2, And your input value was

```
1
```

which produces this array

```
array(
    4=>1,
    1=>1,
    1=>1
);
```

Now as you may know php array keys are unique, so the first one(1) key is overwritten by the second one(1) key, resulting in this

```
$arr4 = array_sum(array(1=>1, 4=>1));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php

And hence the sum of 2

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `array_fill_keys` will use the the values 4, 1, and 1 and the keys and set their values to 1.

```
$arr2 = array("apple" => 4, "banana" => 1, "lemon"=> 1);
```

will become

```
$arr2 = array(4 => "apple", 1 => "banana", 1 => "lemon");
```

The two keys as 1 will cancel out, so you're left with only two values in the array. Then PHP will replace all the values with the value provided, which is one.

Your final array will look like this,

```
$arr2 = array(4 => 1, 1 => 1);
```

And `array_sum`, adds the values in the array, thus `1 + 1 = 2`.

Comment: array fill keys does not flip the values it uses  the first parameter as the keys and the second as the value   -  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php, so $arr3 is  array("apple"=>1,"banana"=>1,"lemon"=>1);

Comment: Array fill keys uses an array's values as the keys for a new array, and fills that array with a given value. The problem is two values in $arr2 are the same so only one key is passed across.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix `using the values of the keys array as keys`, So it's taking `4` (the value of the key), and swapping it with `apple` (the key). It is [flipping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php). It changes the values and keys. If it's following your logic, then array_sum should yield `three`, but it clearly does not.

Comment: @DaveChen - clearly it does not flip the array according to the php documentation, that function is array_flip.  such as this would give the same result array( 'a'=>1, 'b'=>1, 'a'=>1) why is that not 3? because keys are not duplicate has nothing to do with flipping them, the OP chose to use numbers thats not the fault of array_fill_keys .

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Can you check my explanation [here](https://eval.in/private/e329a4adff50c9)?

Comment: @DaveChen - I don't care enough about it to argue the point, it may be "essentially" flipping the array in this use case, but it's improper to say that it flips arrays, that was my point.  That could be easy misunderstood as the way it functions which it does not.  And that is not the reason for the sum, if you used any array with duplicate values those keys would be removed.

Answer (score 0):

array_fill_keys() is given an array of keys and produces a new array using those keys and a defined value. $arr2 contains two values which are the same "1" which means when you use it to produce $arr4, only two values are created.

If you need to use the keys from the first arrays you should consider using array_keys to use the keys, rather than the values:

```
$keys1 = array_keys($arr1);
$keys2 = array_keys($arr2);
$arr3 = array_fill_keys($keys1, 1);
$arr4 = array_fill_keys($keys2, 1);
```

This way the keys of (arr1 and arr3) and (arr2 and arr4) will match up.

Enjoy.